# Update Android Gitlab CI/CD pipeline from Java 1.8 to Java 11?

Tags: java, android, build.gradle, gitlab-ci.yml

Project builds successfully on local PC in Android Studio after upgrade to Gradle 7 but not in Gitlab pipeline.

Gradle 7.0.2 requires Java 11.

The error message in Gitlab pipeline is

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
> You can try some of the following options:
> - changing the IDE settings.
> - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
> - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

(check your gradle version by executing the below command on the local machine from the project directory at the command prompt )

```
 .\gradlew --version
```

**.gitlab-ci.yml:**
The original complete .gitlab-ci.yml script is described in this post from 2018 which works with Java 1.8 (not with Java 11) AND with gradle 4 (not with gradle 7) on Gitlab: https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2018/10/24/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-android-projects/

**on local pc in Android Studio: Upgrading from Java 1.8 to 11**

On the local pc in Android Studio upgrading from Java 1.8 to 11 required 3 steps(and a reboot):

Step 1: adjusting the Gradle setting in Android Studio to Java 11 or higher

(Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 4: File->Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Build Tools->Gradle->Gradle JDK)
[image]

Step 2: updating the JAVA_HOME variable (Windows "Edit the System Environment Variables"[[image]

Set the JAVA_HOME variable to the same as in Android Studio

Step 3: update build.gradle from JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 to JavaVersion.VERSION_11
[image]

[image]

Change it in Menu Project Structure also by selecting Open (in Lightbulb or on top right)
[image]
Reboot.

**.gitlab-ci.yml : Upgrading from Java 1.8 to 11**

The original .gitlab-ci.yml produced the below error with Gradle 7.0.2 when the code built on the new gradle version 7.0.2 was pushed to gitlab:

1st error with original gitlab.ci.yaml

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
> You can try some of the following options:
> - changing the IDE settings.
> - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
> - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

Changing the image in .gitlab-ci.yml on line 1
from

```
image: openjdk:8-jdk
```

To

```
image: openjdk:11-jdk
```

produced another error:

> $ echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}" >/dev/null
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
> at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.(SchemaModule.java:156)
> at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.(SchemaModule.java:75)
> at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
> at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
> at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
> ... 5 more
> Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
> 00:01
> ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

I have spent a lot of time on this issue.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the part from the original script which needs changing:

From this:

```
image: openjdk:8-jdk

variables:
  ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "28"
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "28.0.2"
  ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS:   "4333796"

before_script:
  - apt-get --quiet update --yes
  - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
  - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}.zip
  - unzip -d android-sdk-linux android-sdk.zip
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}" >/dev/null
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools" >/dev/null
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}" >/dev/null
  - export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
  - export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
  - chmod +x ./gradlew
  # temporarily disable checking for EPIPE error and use yes to accept all licenses
  - set +o pipefail
  - yes | android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
  - set -o pipefail
```

To this:

```
image: openjdk:11-jdk

variables:
  ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "31"
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "32.0.0"
  ANDROID_COMMAND_LINE_TOOLS: "7583922"
  GRADLE_OPTS: "-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false"


before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=$(pwd)/.gradle
  - chmod +x ./gradlew
  - apt-get --quiet update --yes
  - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
  - mkdir -p android-sdk-linux/cmdline-tools
  - export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
  - cd android-sdk-linux/cmdline-tools
  - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-${ANDROID_COMMAND_LINE_TOOLS}_latest.zip
  - unzip android-sdk.zip
  - rm android-sdk.zip
  - mv cmdline-tools version
  - echo y | version/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}" >/dev/null
  - echo y | version/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools" >/dev/null
  - echo y | version/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}" >/dev/null
  - export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools/
  # temporarily disable checking for EPIPE error and use yes to accept all licenses
  - set +o pipefail
  - yes | version/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
  - set -o pipefail
  - cd ../../
  - chmod +x ./gradlew
```

**note that the Variables were also upgraded in the .gitlab-ci-yml.
They are also located in the local build.gradle here: [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it by the template .yml file.

You can check the following link:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Android.latest.gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).